# SmartSheet add row to bottom in python SDK

Tags: python, smartsheet-api

Using the python library and the 2.0 API docs.  I am trying to add a row but keep getting the error: `"message": "Required object attribute(s) are missing from your request: row.id."`

The problem seems to be with the `new_row.to_bottom=True` statement.  Am I mis understanding or is there an error in the API?
I also noticed that when I added `to_top` in the same call, the message came back with `only toTop or toBottom in a single call.` I tried again with that syntax and still no luck.

```
import smartsheet
...
new_row = ss_client.models.Row()
new_row.to_bottom = True       #also tried .toBottom=True
new_cell = ss_client.models.Cell()
new_cell.column_id = 9380123454964
new_cell.value = 'update'
new_cell.strict = False
new_row.cells.append(new_cell)
updated_row = ss_client.Sheets.update_rows(1234567,[new_row]) #also tried new_row outside of []


Response: {
status: 400 Bad Request
content: {
{
    "detail": {
        "index": 0
    },
    "errorCode": 1012,
    "message": "Required object attribute(s) are missing from your request: row.id.",
    "refId": "152g54q6e89sd"
}
}
```

Anyone know how to fix this?  is the SDK still on 1.0 or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're attempting to update a row that doesn't exist yet. Until the row has actually been created, you don't know what the row id is, because it hasn't been assigned one by the server. Replace `update_rows` with `add_rows`.

```
ss_client.Sheets.add_rows(<sheet_id>,[new_row])
```